# The "using this site" question shouldn't have been migrated

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[How to ask questions regarding my current job when coworkers use this site too?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3727/how-to-ask-questions-regarding-my-current-job-when-coworkers-use-this-site-too) was asked on main and migrated to meta, in my opinion incorrectly.  If somebody had asked a question about using Reddit or Glassdoor or LinkedIn or some other site to say things he might not want his coworkers to see, would we have migrated it?  No, because it's a question about *navigating the workplace* -- specifically, about how to stay out of coworkers' view on employment-related corners of the Internet.  That the site in question is *this* site does not make it a meta question, any more than a programming question on SO is meta just because an SE developer asked it.

I would like to see this question back on main, where it will come up in search results and be offered as a related question when people start to ask similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

[**I disagree.**](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3727/how-to-ask-questions-regarding-my-current-job-when-coworkers-use-this-site-too#comment9306_3727) I can see a version of the question being appropriate for the main site, but **as written the question is specifically about how to use the Workplace site** in the context of the broader network of StackExchange sites. You are *guaranteed* to get answers that depend on the way SE accounts work.

There may be some confusion because the OP actually has two questions:

- how do I ask question on Workplace if I'm worried about my identity being discovered/linked to SO?
- what do I do when my colleagues find out I asked an embarrassing/unprofessional question on a forum?

The former belongs on meta. The second doesn't. Since the second is entirely theoretical the post should be edited down to refocus the question on the meta question.

To illustrate the point: we can replace Workplace with any other potentially embarrassing site like Parenting or some of the hobby sites (Gaming, SciFi, Anime) and not get a substantially different question, because the OP's key question is:

> How should someone concerned with their coworkers discovering **their potentially relationship-damaging questions on Stack Exchange?**

We don't have a monopoly on questions that could damage someone's relationship if a friend/colleague found it.

This could even be moved to SE's meta, but strategies for asking anonymous questions are likely to be substantially different for Workplace issues.

Comment: I agree with your disagreement. I think this question fits Meta well.